# function doesn't get called when a hidden reference is associated with it

Tags: python, flask

I'm scratching my head for days as I don't get it why the function **crypto_insert()** doesn't get called when I click refresh stats as I added a hidden reference.

the app is declared here:

****init**.py**

```
from tracker.crypto.crypto_portfolio import crypto_portfolio
app.register_blueprint(crypto_portfolio)
```

The Blueprint route is declared here:

**core.py**

```
@core.route('/crypto_insert', methods=['GET','POST'])
def crypto_insert():
    return render_template('crypto_portfolio.html')
```

The python/flask part is here located here:

**crypto_portfolio.py**

```
# Coingecko API library
from pycoingecko import CoinGeckoAPI

crypto_portfolio = Blueprint('crypto_portfolio',__name__)
print('******************HELLOO1111**************')

@crypto_portfolio.route('/crypto_insert', methods=['GET','POST'])
@login_required
def crypto_insert():
    print('******************HELLOO2222**************')
    if request.form.get("ident") == "formCrypto":
        print('******************HELLO3333**************')

        crypto_token = 'bitcoin'
        crypto_currency = 'usd'
        print('******************HELLOO4444**************')
        print(crypto_token)

        return render_template('crypto_portfolio.html',
                                formCrypto=form,
                                crypto_token=crypto_token,
                                crypto_currency=crypto_currency,
                                )
```

The flask/bootstrap part to render the values are shown here:

**crypto_portfolio.html**

```
{% extends "base.html" %}
{% block content %}

<!-- Container for the whole page -->
  <div class="container">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-12">
        <div class="bg-light p-3">

<!-- Flash messages section -->
          <div class="forms">
            <div class="formCrypto">
              <form method="post" action="{{ url_for('core.crypto_insert') }}">

                      <div class="alert alert-success alert-dismissable" role="alert">
                        <button type="button" class="btn-close" data-bs-dismiss="alert" aria-label="Close">
                        </button>
                      </div>

<!-- Portfolio Summary and refresh button section -->
                <h2><b>Portfolio</b> Summary:
                  <button type="submit" class="btn btn btn-primary float-end" data-bs-toggle="modal" data-bs-target="#modalrefresh">Refresh Stats</button> </h2>
                  <input type=hidden name="ident" value="formCrypto">
              </form>
            </div>
          </div>

<!-- Portfolio Summary section -->
          <div class="container">
            <div class="row align-items-start">
              <div class="col">
                <b>Total Invested: </b>${{crypto_token}}
              </div>
              <div class="col">
                <b>Total Earnings: </b>${{crypto_currency}}
              </div>

            </div>
          </div>


        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

  {% endblock %}
```

But in the debug terminal only hello1 is printed:

> ******************HELLOO1111**************

What an I missing here?

Comment: What do you mean by “click refresh stats”. Can you explain what you mean by “added a hidden reference”? Added a reference where, to what?  Outlook a `core` a blueprint too? How are your blueprints registered? Please try to provide a [mcve] including a Flask instance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems that you are defining 2 routes for `/crypto_insert` (in `core.py` and in `crypto_portfolio.py` ) ; And only calling core.crypto_insert in the form in `crypto_portfolio.html`.

For a better understanding I suggest updating `crypto_portfolio.py` with :

```
# Coingecko API library
from pycoingecko import CoinGeckoAPI

crypto_portfolio = Blueprint('crypto_portfolio',__name__)
print('******************HELLOO1111**************')

@crypto_portfolio.route('/crypto-insert-with-form-handling', methods=['GET','POST'])
@login_required
def crypto_insert_with_form_handling():
    print('******************HELLOO2222**************')
    if request.form.get("ident") == "formCrypto":
        print('******************HELLO3333**************')

        crypto_token = 'bitcoin'
        crypto_currency = 'usd'
        print('******************HELLOO4444**************')
        print(crypto_token)

        return render_template('crypto_portfolio.html',
                                formCrypto=form,
                                crypto_token=crypto_token,
                                crypto_currency=crypto_currency,
                                )
    
    return render_template('crypto_portfolio.html')
```

and to have a POST request at the same url, update the the line `crypto_portfolio.html` :

```
<form method="post" action="{{ url_for('core.crypto_insert') }}">
```

to

```
<form method="post" action="#">
```

You can now try `/crypto-insert-with-form-handling` and `/crypto_insert` .

Comment: I got it fixed, with Flask you have to have a POST function that will work for all front-end buttons and fields and then use the hidden identifications to select which button and which fields go where... Thank you all for your help!!